# Why does PSEXEC work if I don't specify a password?

Tags: windows-server-2008, pstools, windows

When I run SysInternals `PSEXEC` to launch a process on a remote machine, if I specify the password in the command line it fails with:

`PsExec could not start cmd.exe on web1928:`
`Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.`

```
psexec \\web1928 -u remoteexec -p mypassword "cmd.exe"
```

or

```
psexec \\web1928 -u web1928\remoteexec -p mypassword "cmd.exe"
```

If I just specify:

```
psexec \\web1928 -u remoteexec "cmd.exe"
```

and type in the password it works just fine.

The originating server is Windows 2003 and the remote server is Windows 2008 SP2. The `remoteexec` account only exists on the remote server and is a member of the `Administrators` group.

Comment: Could it be that the password contains characters that need to the password to be in quotes?

Comment: @john - bingo mate! There's a dollar and a grave ($ and ^) in the password. Didn't think these would interfere. Make that an answer and I'll upvote and tick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could it be that the password contains characters that need to the password to be in quotes?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't provide a username your current authentication is passed through.  When passing the -u paramater you may need to specify the username as DOMAIN\username.  I am going to guess that psexec is trying to authenticate as the local account 'remoteexec' on the computer instead of a domain account like you expected.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did try specifying `WEB1928\remoteexec` as the user, but sadly no joy.

Comment: @zoredach - john's comment under the question nailed it. But thanks fort the suggestion.